# How can I match the rotation of one Object3D to another (different parents, different coords)?

Tags: 3d, three.js

I want to match the rotation of a reference object in three.js. The object3d I want to rotate and the reference object might have different parents in different local transforms, but I want them to align rotation-wise in the global space.

```
function matchRotationOfReference(myObj3D, referenceObj3D) {
    // what do I do here?
}
```

I know how to do this for position vectors like so:

```
var pos = new THREE.Vector3();
function matchPositionOfReference(myObj3D, referenceObj3D) {
    referenceObj3D.updateMatrixWorld();
    pos.setFromMatrixPosition(referenceObj3D.matrixWorld);
    myObj3D.parentEl.worldToLocal(pos);
    myObj3D.position.copy(pos);
}
```

Comment: Just a note: I tried creating a scene with two groups with fixed translations and random rotations, each containing a cube. This worked as expected. I then tried to get the world matrix from the one cube, and apply just its rotation to the second cube. This did _not_ work. (Both had `cube.autoUpdateMatrix = false;`.) I tried again by copying the `quaternion` from one cube to the other. Still no luck. I can see the world matrix updating, but it seems to have no effect. Not sure what I was doing wrong, and I don't have time to debug it. Maybe this idea will give you one to try.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'd normally ask what you have tried so far, because it sounds like a fairly easy thing to accomplish. But when I tried it myself, I wasn't able to make it work, and I had to jump through several hoops to make it work correctly.*

In the example code below, I start with two `Group`s, each containing a cube. Each `Group` also has its own transformation/rotation. This makes the cubes initially face in different directions.

In the `animate` function, you can see when the "Spin" checkbox is checked, I tear apart (`decompose`) the `redCube`'s world matrix, saving its `quaternion` (used for rotation) into `tempQ`. I do the same thing to `greenCube`. I then re-build (`compose`) `greenCube`'s world matrix, using its original translation and scale, but using `redCube`'s quaternion. (And remember, this is the *world* quaternion, so it's not affected by local transformations.)

This works because I took a direct shortcut to the most important part of transforming the object: its world matrix. I disabled updating matrices across the board, which removes a lot of the convenience of three.js, but it allowed me to work directly with the world matrices without anything overwriting them.

Here's hoping someone can find a more elegant solution for you.

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, stats, redCube, greenCube, t, q, tempQ, s;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
 FOV = 35,
 NEAR = 1,
 FAR = 1000;

var doUpdates = false;
var spinBox = document.getElementById("spin");
spinBox.addEventListener("change", function(){
  doUpdates = spinBox.checked;
});

function populateScene(){

  var axis = new THREE.Vector3();
  var pos = new THREE.Vector3();
  var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10);

  axis.set(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random());
  pos.set(-10, 0, 0);
  var p1 = new THREE.Group();
  p1.matrixWorld.makeRotationAxis(axis, Math.random());
  p1.matrixWorld.setPosition(pos);
 redCube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "red" }));
 p1.add(redCube);
  redCube.updateMatrixWorld(true);
  
  scene.add(p1);
  
  axis.set(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random());
  pos.set(10, 0, 0);
  var p2 = new THREE.Group();
  p2.matrixWorld.makeRotationAxis(axis, Math.random());
  p2.matrixWorld.setPosition(pos);
 greenCube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "green" }));
 p2.add(greenCube);
  greenCube.updateMatrixWorld(true);
  
  scene.add(p2);
}

function init() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "slateGray";

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });

 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
 document.body.style.margin = "0";
 document.body.style.padding = "0";

 scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.autoUpdate = false;

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
 camera.position.z = 50;
 scene.add(camera);

 controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
 controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.5;
 controls.rotateSpeed = 3;

 var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);
 camera.add(light);

 stats = new Stats();
 stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
 stats.domElement.style.top = '0';
 document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);

 resize();
 window.onresize = resize;

 populateScene();
  
  t = new THREE.Vector3();
  q = new THREE.Quaternion();
  tempQ = new THREE.Quaternion();
  s = new THREE.Vector3();

 animate();
}

function resize() {
 WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
 if (renderer && camera && controls) {
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  controls.handleResize();
 }
}

function render() {
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  camera.updateMatrixWorld(true);
  
  if(doUpdates){
    redCube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    redCube.rotation.y += 0.02;
    redCube.rotation.z += 0.03;
    redCube.updateMatrixWorld(true);
    
    redCube.matrixWorld.decompose(t, tempQ, s);
    greenCube.matrixWorld.decompose(t, q, s);
    greenCube.matrixWorld.compose(t, tempQ, s);
  }
  
 render();
 controls.update();
 stats.update();
}

function threeReady() {
 init();
}

(function () {
 function addScript(url, callback) {
  callback = callback || function () { };
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.addEventListener("load", callback);
  script.setAttribute("src", url);
  document.head.appendChild(script);
 }

 addScript("https://threejs.org/build/three.js", function () {
  addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js", function () {
   addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js", function () {
    threeReady();
   })
  })
 })
})();
```

```html
<label style="display: block; float: right; width: 200px;">Spin:<input type="checkbox" id="spin" /></label>
```