# How to set child object rotation using quaternion in world coordinates using ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I am a newbie to ThreeJS and i am trying to set the rotation of the child objects by using Quaternion like the following.

```
childObject.setRotationFromQuaternion(quaternion)
```

But this rotation applies to the object in local coordinates. What i want is to apply rotation globally(in world coordinates).Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419843/how-can-i-match-the-rotation-of-one-object3d-to-another-different-parents-diff. Also, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15735090/1461008).

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley. Actually i am trying to rotate the skeleton bone's rotation in world coordinates using quaternion. Is there any way i can rotate it directly in world coordinates ?